# Vue Make only one specific component from v-for react to prop not other

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

issue: Vuejs, have a component(file upload) that is rendered inside parent in `v-for` loop. I am passing a prop to it to conditionally render a  remove button(basically removes background from div kind of a preview). How do I make only specific component from that loop to react to the show/hide prop and not others?
E.g. `v-for` rendered 3 `FileUpload` components. All got `isRemoveBtnShown` prop. How to make `FileUpload1` show button, and `FileUplod2 and 3` not to show?

parent:

```
<FileUpload v-for="(field, index) in uploadFieldsToRender"
                    ref="file-upload"
                    :key="field"
                    :docPageTitle="field"
                    :isLoading="isLoading"
                    :shouldDocsBeScanned="shouldDocsBeScanned"
                    :isUploadError="isUploadError"
                    :isRemoveBtnShown="isRemoveBtnShown"
                    @fileUpload="handleFileUpload"
                    @fileRemoval="handleFileRemoval"
                    @fileScan="handleFileScan"
                    @fileUploadMounted="onFileUploadMounted"
                />
```

FileUpload:

```
        <div v-else class="controls">
            <button
                v-if="shouldDocsBeScanned"
                class="button btn-scan"
                @click="() => $emit('fileScan', this.$refs)"
            >
                <span class="btn-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div v-if="true" class="upload-options">
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="file"
                        class="image-upload"
                        accept="image/*, application/pdf"
                        @change="$event => this.$emit('fileUpload', $event, this.$refs)"
                    />
                </label>
            </div>
            <button
                v-if="isRemoveBtnShown"
                class="button btn-remove"
                @click="() => this.$emit('fileRemoval', this.$refs)"
                >
                <span class="btn-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
```

props:

```
        shouldDocsBeScanned: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        isRemoveBtnShown: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
```

Cant use `$refs` as they are not reactive(could have checked if the cmp has background or not)
Many thanks!

Comment: You have share one prop value eg.isRemoveBtnShown so when you click button update , that value in parent will make update `all component at the same time` . So how about handle that function and data in **component only** or **you need to use array props**

Comment: You could make it an Array of Objects and add the property to each via a map otherwise you change the same value on either button

Comment: thanks guys. I get it that I share a prop between all three.. just cant figure out how to  play it so only component that i had just loaded a file to would show that delete btn and others would just ave upload icon still

Comment: I'll try @hs-dev2MR approach see if I can manage it properly

Comment: still no luck. could someone provide with some pseudo-code pls?

Comment: @Badgy has the correct answer here. This is an issue with your data design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out a way to fix my issue by
1) moving `isRemoveBtnShown` to `FileUpload` itself
2) giving `FileUpload` cmp in parent a `ref` of its `field` then gettin my current component by means of `this.$refs[field]` and change its internal prop (`isRemoveBtnShown`) to desired.

Works as a charm, no sibling `FileUpoload`s are effected